# jQuery file download - ready function instead of click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following jQuery code that when a hyperlink is clicked, it downloads the file of the hyperlink href. While it is preparing the file, it displays a please wait message.

The href code is:

```
<a class="fileDownloadCustomRichExperience" href="pdf.php">Report Download</a>
```

I want to be able to make the code below run using the $( document ).ready(function() {  instead of $(document).on("click")

I tried the ready(function) but couldnt get the href to work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on("click", "a.fileDownloadCustomRichExperience", function () {

        var $preparingFileModal = $("#preparing-file-modal");

        $preparingFileModal.dialog({ modal: true });

        $.fileDownload($(this).prop('href'), {
            successCallback: function (url) {

                $preparingFileModal.dialog('close');
            },
            failCallback: function (responseHtml, url) {

                $preparingFileModal.dialog('close');
                $("#error-modal").dialog({ modal: true });
            }
        });
        return false; //this is critical to stop the click event which will trigger a normal file download!
    });
});
```

*** SOLVED BELOW: ***

```
$(function () {
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var $preparingFileModal = $("#preparing-file-modal");

    $preparingFileModal.dialog({ modal: true });

    $.fileDownload('pdf.php', {
        successCallback: function (url) {

            $preparingFileModal.dialog('close');
        },
        failCallback: function (responseHtml, url) {

            $preparingFileModal.dialog('close');
            $("#error-modal").dialog({ modal: true });
        }
    });
    return false; //this is critical to stop the click event which will trigger a normal file download!
});
```

});

Comment: The code you have provided doesn't show you trying the ready function...

Comment: the only problem with changing click to ready i see here is the usage of "this" to reference the clicked link.. if this was instead changed to $("a.fileDownloadCustomRichExperience").prop("href") it should work

Comment: Seems the attempt only confirms you should change $(this) which is now the document to select the <a> tag

Comment: clancer, i tried $.fileDownload($("pdf.php").prop("href") still doesnt seem to work. any ideas?

Comment: `$("pdf.php").prop("href")` doesn't make sense. did you mean, `"pdf.php"`?

Comment: Kevin, i've tried $.fileDownload('pdf.php'), { too but doesnt work.

Comment: I got it, its supposed to be: $.fileDownload('pdf.php', {